How to correctly handle webform submissions in D7
I've got a webform that registers people for events on a D7/Civi site. In general it's been working fine for several years. I've just noticed that in certain circumstances it is is not working properly and I'm trying to work how best to address the problem:
The form can register multiple people. The first contact is configured such that if the user is logged in, the first contact is pre-filled with the user's details. All good. In circumstances where the user is logged in but doesn't want to register themselves (e.g. they are only registering other people), I've used the "Not you? alert message to present a link that the user can click to re-present the form without their details being pre-filled (i.e the link appends "?cid1=0" to the URL.
It was my assumption, perhaps wrong, that by doing this the user could then enter details for the first contact, and those details would be used to create (if appropriate) a contact record in CiviCRM, and register that contact for the event.
What I'm seeing in practice is that while all of the entered details for the first contact are being captured in the webform submission, none of this data is being pushed into CiviCRM, so no contact record is created or updated, no event registration is being recorded (and no payment is being taken). The form works as expected for subsequent contacts.
I'm about to change the form so that users are advised to log out if they don't want to register themselves, but this doesn't sit well. Am I using the wrong approach to enable logged in users to register others and not themselves?
